# Explain this Groovy code?

Tags: groovy

```
def foo(n) {
    return {n += it}
}
```

Comment: `question.getContext()` - NullPointerException... It looks like a closure, but we might need a bit more context.

Comment: A nicer way (IMHO) to achieve the same would be by using `curry` -- see http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/04/groovy-goodness-new-ways-to-curry.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The code defines a function/method `foo` that returns a closure. For the purpose of understanding this code, you can think of a closure as a method that has no name and is not attached to any object.

The closure can be invoked by passing it a single argument. The value returned by the closure will be `n += it` where `it` is the default name used to refer to a closure's argument. If you wanted the closure's argument to have a different name, e.g. `closureParam` you would need to define it explicity:

```
def foo(n) {
    return {closureParam -> n += closureParam}
}
```

The `->` separates the closure's parameter list from the closure body. If no parameter list is defined, the default is a single parameter named `it`. Maybe an example of invoking the closure will help:

```
Closure closure = foo(2)
def closureReturnVal = closure.call(4) 
assert closureReturnVal == 6 // because 4 + 2 == 6

// you can omit .call when calling a closure, so the following also works
closure = foo(3)
assert 8 == closure(5)
```

Comment: good one. looks like a confusing closure though. currying seems like a better alternative.

Comment: ya ya currying is a very powerful way to handle functions :)

Comment: The answer is missing one important aspect to this. The returned closure is an accumulator. n is a state kept between invocations. so foo(3) will produce a closure that starts with n=3. Calling closure(5) will not only return 8, it will also set n to 8. Thus doing closure(5) again will result in 13. I think you cannot do this with currying

Answer (score -2):

I believe it's returning the double of the value you pass in, or a a concatenation of the same string twice if you give it a string.

Comment: The closure you've described would be `{it * 2}`